# Converting string value to float value

Tags: c#

In my code i have converting string value to float value. In my code: guns - array(size = 5) and Chargunsinformations - string value.

```
guns[gunsNum] = float.Parse(ChargunsInformation);
```

Unity gives me an error:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
> System.Number.ParseSingle (System.String value,
> System.Globalization.NumberStyles options,
> System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) (at
> <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0) System.Single.Parse
> (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style,
> System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at
> <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0) System.Single.Parse
> (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at
> <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0) System.Convert.ToSingle
> (System.String value) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> StartOfAllScript.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player
> Scripts/StartOfAllScript.cs:35)

Please, help me. I was trying to solve this problem for 2 hours.

Comment: What is value in `ChargunsInformation` and why did you add `p` tag for this question? You can try `float.TryParse()` instead of `float.parse()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess problem is related to your system culture. Please try following code snippet

```
guns[gunsNum] = float.Parse(ChargunsInformation, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Player Scripts\StartOfAllScript.cs(34,66): error CS0103: The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context
gives me unity

Comment: Have you added System.Globalization namespace? Could you please provide value which you want to convert and your system current culture?

Comment: Yes, i added. I want to convert Chargunsinformations to a value of a guns array

Comment: What is value in "Chargunsinformations" variable which you want to convert? And could you please provide your system current culture. so, it is helpful to reproduce problem?

Comment: Chargunsinformations - string value, which i want to convert. And my culture is ru-RU

Comment: Could you please try :-  guns[gunsNum] = float.Parse(ChargunsInformation, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

Comment: I have doubt about "ChargunsInformation". Could you please check in ChargunsInformation has proper string value. might be there is any space or other stuff which can cause problem? I think "ChargunsInformation" was not in a correct format? Take a look at it while debugging, what does it contain?

Comment: oh, thank u, i solved this problem. The problem was "ChargunsInformation" contained number, space, number. And my program tried to convert space to a number. Thank u. How can i thank u?

Comment: If this is helpful. Could please upvote it. So, others might get help to solve there's probably.